# react-testing-library: cannot close the dropdown menu for MUI Select

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have an SelectExample.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { InputLabel, MenuItem, FormControl, Select, Typography } from "@mui/material";>

export default function SelectExample() {

const [country, setCountry] = useState([]);

return (
    <div>
        <Typography variant="h6">Selected country: {country}</Typography>
        <FormControl>
        <InputLabel  data-testid="country2" id="country">Country</InputLabel>
        <Select
        multiple
        data-testid="country"
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setCountry(value)}
        value={country}
        style={{ minWidth: 120 }}
        >
            <MenuItem value="brazil">Brazil</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="japan">Japan</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="usa">United States</MenuItem>
        </Select>
        </FormControl>
    </div>
)}
```

and a SelectExample.test.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { getByDisplayValue, getByRole, render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import UserEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import SelectExample from "./SelectExample";

test("select", async () => {
  await act(async () => await render(<SelectExample />));
  UserEvent.click(getByRole(screen.getByTestId("country"), "button"));
  await waitFor(() => UserEvent.click(screen.getByText(/brazil/i)));
  UserEvent.click(getByRole(screen.getByTestId("country"), "button")); // this line do not perform the expected behaviour
    // would like to assert if brazil is in the document
    screen.debug()
});
```

I want to perform some user action before I start my test:

- Step 1: user click the "Country" button once -> dropdown menu appear
- Step 2: user select 'brazil' -> 'brazil' appear in under the "Country" text
- Step 3: user click the "Country" button once -> close the dropdown menu

For Step1 and Step2. It works fine. But for Step3. There is some problem...
If I add one more click event for my button after selected brazil. The following error occurs:

which will not occur if I remove that line.
I do not understand why this error exist. and how to perform Step3 for my testing

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example using https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-austin-p1rr9j?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your codesandbox is missing a few dependencies and needs a bit of an update.

Answer (score 0):

```
await user.keyboard("{Tab}")
```

This code is what has only worked for me so far.

Note: replace user with UserEvent in your case